# Bootstrap 3 Not applying css local links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently trying to make a flat website for my landlord. I am using the Bootstrap 3 framework. However, my navigation bar only pops up as an unordered list rather than a horizontal bar. The CSS code I'm using can be found [here](https://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.css). I get no error messages except for the CSS code's first line `@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic");`: "value start only applies to XSL (level 0)."

**My HTML code**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <title>(APT name witheld for privacy)</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial=scale=1">
  <meta name="generator" content="Aptana Studio 3">
  <meta name="keywords" content="apartments">
  <meta name="description" content="Cheap living">
  <meta name="description" content="Cheap apartments">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" type="style/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-theme.css" type="style/css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrap.cdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div id="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">(APT name witheld for privacy)</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li class="nav-header">Company</li>
              <li><a href="History.html">Our History</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="StaffTeam.html">Staff Team</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Amenities.html">Amenities</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Rooms <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li class="nav-header"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Rates and Listings</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Floor Plans</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="nav-header">Renting</li>
              <li><a href="Application.html">Application</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="FAQ.html">FAQ</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

What I don't understand is why it's not working. I linked the JQuery before JavaScript and have tried it the other way around, but it won't work. The navigation bar code is the same as I have found on tutorial websites but nothing seems to work. Where have I gone wrong?

I can't figure it out. I'm 99% sure that all of my CSS page linking is okay since I don't have it in different folders (although I probably should for organization reasons, but I'll do that later). The navigation bar is supposed to look like this without a search area and button: [image: look like this without a search area and button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type att again

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="...."></script>
```

And I think that `bootstrap.min.js` has something wrong.

I made the changes and it worked.

copy and paste this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that I changed the jquery version and the bootstrap url. And since the dropdown elements are not displaying correctly consider see the source code of this page [http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/]

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your problem

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
```

check the type attribute. It shouldn't be like this `type="style/css"`

Comment: The bar works now, but my dropdown menu won't work on click.